# How do I track which Korok seeds are left?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

All I’ve got left to do in Breath of the Wild is find all the Korok seeds. I’ve found almost half. I don’t actually want to walk every square inch of Hyrule looking for them. Are there any guides/maps/etc that I can use? I’d like something that I can check off/track as I go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best of luck grabbing those last couple seeds, as you have no doubt noticed there are **a lot** of them.

I found that [this interactive map](https://www.zeldadungeon.net/breath-of-the-wild-interactive-map/) is quite useful as you can filter it to show the location of all the seeds. Additionally when you click on the little seed icon, there is a small info window that pops up with a small photo and descriptor of that specific seed.

Additionally, in those little info windows there is the option to mark the seeds as completed/not completed. Then you can use the little gear in the top left corner to hide "completed" seeds, so you can track your progress as you go.

Comment: There are 900 Korok Seeds in total. So yes, there are **a lot** :)

Comment: Yup, that is where I called it a day for my save file. I got all shrines, but I am not so into completionism to go for all seeds.

Comment: There's also no benefit from finding them all, from what I understand. The devs added so many precisely because they wanted to ensure we wouldn't have the pressure of tracking every single one all down - you only need about half of them to fully upgrade everything. But hey, completionists gonna complete.

Comment: @Alex Yup, I think that was a good design choice by them. Though to be fair you do get *something* for collecting all the korok Seeds, it just isn't useful. (and kinda stinks)

Comment: @Malco Ah yeah, I remember now! What a pile of...uh, garbage.

Comment: @Malco, I think you should add that with the Master Trials DLC (IIRC) comes the Korok mask which makes tracking them even easier.

Comment: @KyleRone I wasn't aware that the mask existed, it would probably be a better answer if you wanted to write it up

Answer (score 6):

@Malco's answer is pretty good, and should be your method you use to find them and mark them off. However, I would like to add that if you have purchased the Master Trials DLC, there unlocks a quest to get a new piece of headgear called the Korok Mask. Check out [this polygon article](https://www.polygon.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-guide-walkthrough/2017/6/30/15898232/korok-mask-find-location-lost-woods-master-trials-dlc) on how to unlock it.

From the article:

> When worn, this mask acts like your sheiklah slate does for shrines,
>   but for koroks.

Using Malco's method plus the mask should get you that totally awesome end reward in no time.

Spolier alert:

> Its a [golden piece of
>  poop](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hestu%27s_Gift).

Answer (score 3):

I'm coming back to the game after many years since playing and beating it (over 5 years ago). I could have sworn I was nearly complete with maybe 40 something left. Apparently I still have a long way to go.

Anyway, I'm not sure if this is something that was added in the DLC but I noticed that *collected* korok seeds are now marked in the map. I don't remember it being like that at all. You just have to zoom in to the closest level to see it.

[image]

So as long as you have a map of the actual korok seed locations (as linked in Malco's answer), you should be able to determine which ones you have collected at a glance, if they are marked on your map. You can compare what you have to the full map.

Comment: And after playing Arceus for so long, it's funny how the control schemes are breaking my brain right now.

Comment: As an aside, I think I did lose a lot of progression. I was wondering why I didn't have the bike yet. I definitely remember using it at some point, but the quests for it on my save show incomplete.